How can I configure SSO in Abp.io to support Azure AD across multiple tenants that are not under the same Azure portal?
I am using the Abp.io 5.3 framework Angular non-layer application. Using the below code
I've successfully implemented Azure AD Single Sign-On (SSO) for my application using the Abp.io 5.3 framework with Angular. However, I now need to extend SSO to include a new domain that isn't managed under my Azure portal. I do have the necessary credentials - client ID, secret key, and tenant ID - for this new tenant's Azure App.
Since these two tenants aren't managed under the same Azure portal, I'm unsure how to proceed with SSO. Is there a method to dynamically load OpenID Connect settings based on the domain name, allowing me to integrate SSO for this new domain alongside the existing implementation?


The easiest way to handle this case in my opinion is to setup your App Registration in Azure as a multitenant App, that way when a user goes to the login page they sign in to their own Entra. You have to read up on the details of Multitenant AppRegistration in Entra.
Hope that helps!
